# getlogin_r() and getlogin() do only work on tty

Tags: c++, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I wrote a test program to check whether getlogin_r() and getlogin() do work or not, because I had problems with them before and could not fix it. In the TTY it works just fine and both functions are returning my username, but executed in the LXDE Terminal, the following error occurs:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

I am running this code an a Raspberry Pi 2 B with Raspbian installed. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char user[64];
    getlogin_r(user,sizeof(user)-1);
    string getlogin_r_str(user);
    string getlogin_str(getlogin());
    cout << "getlogin_r(): " << getlogin_r_str << endl << "getlogin(): " << getlogin_str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused because the LXDE terminal not updating the utmp information which records all logged in users and [`getlogin`](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/sysdeps_2unix_2getlogin_8c_source.html) determines the username from that information.

You should accept that it is possible for `getlogin` to return a null pointer and deal with it gracefully, e.g. by using `getpwuid` if `getlogin` fails:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

std::string get_username() {
    struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid(getuid());
    if (pwd)
        return pwd->pw_name;
    else
        return "(?)";
}
```